# How to combine arrays to 2d array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have googled to do this but I think I am lacking something to make it work and after the merging I will save it to csv file or mysql db.

This is the sample data:

```
01 2015-09-03 08:01
01 2015-09-03 11:03
01 2015-09-03 13:15
01 2015-09-03 17:12
07 2015-09-03 08:15
07 2015-09-03 17:06
01 2015-09-04 08:05
01 2015-09-04 11:03
```

I want the resulting array to be like this before saving it to a csv file:

```
01 | 2015-09-03 | 08:01 | 11:03 | 13:15 | 17:12
07 | 2015-09-03 | 08:15 | 17:06
01 | 2015-09-04 | 08:05 | 11:03
```

creating a header based on the number of elements it have. I tried this code:

```
foreach($line as $value){
fputcsv($converted,$value,"\t");//write the new array to csv
}
```

Comment: The one that I posted the foreach loop.

Comment: are date time and id three different columns?

Comment: yes its a multidimensional array.

Comment: Post your array structure instead along with expected output

Comment: the sample data was the array structure having duplicates in ID and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `explode` function to convert your string to an array:

```
$categories = [];

foreach($lines as $line) {
  $array = explode(' ', $line);

  // Then you can store your data using column 1 and 2 as a key
  $key = $array[0] . $array[1];
  $categories[$key][] = $array;
}

// finally, you can go through the $categories array
foreach ($categories as $category) {
   $csv = [$category[0][0], $category[0][1]];
   foreach ($category as $value) {
     $csv[] = $value;
   }
   fputcsv($handle, $csv);
}
```

The naming of the vars is terrible but I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: I will try the code and it looks like it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<?php
$lines = "
01 2015-09-03 08:01
01 2015-09-03 11:03
01 2015-09-03 13:15
01 2015-09-03 17:12
07 2015-09-03 08:15
07 2015-09-03 17:06
01 2015-09-04 08:05
01 2015-09-04 11:03
";
$line_array = explode("\n", $lines);

$csv_line_array = array();
$csv = 0;
$time = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($line_array); $i++) {
    if ($i < (sizeof($line_array) - 1)) {
        if (substr($line_array[$i], 0, 13) == substr($line_array[$i + 1], 0, 13)) {
            $time = $time . " | " . substr($line_array[$i + 1], 14, 5);
            $csv_line_array[$csv] = $line_array[$i] . " | " . $time;
            $csv++;
        } else {
            $time = substr($line_array[$i + 1], 14, 5);
            $csv_line_array[$csv] = $line_array[$i];
        }
    }
}
$csv_line_array2 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($csv_line_array); $i++) {
    if ($i < (sizeof($csv_line_array) - 1)) {
        if (substr($csv_line_array[$i], 0, 13) == substr($csv_line_array[$i + 1], 0, 13)) {
            if (strlen($csv_line_array[$i]) < strlen($csv_line_array[$i + 1]))
                unset($csv_line_array[$i]);
            else
                $csv_line_array[$i] = $csv_line_array[$i + 1];
        }
    }

}

/*if (strlen($csv_line_array[sizeof($csv_line_array)]) < strlen($csv_line_array[sizeof($csv_line_array) - 1]))
    $csv_line_array[sizeof($csv_line_array)] = $csv_line_array[sizeof($csv_line_array) - 1];
else
    unset($csv_line_array[$i]);*/

var_dump($line_array);
var_dump($csv_line_array);
?>
```

will output something like this:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '01 2015-09-03 08:01' (length=19)
  2 => string '01 2015-09-03 11:03' (length=19)
  3 => string '01 2015-09-03 13:15' (length=19)
  4 => string '01 2015-09-03 17:12' (length=19)
  5 => string '07 2015-09-03 08:15' (length=19)
  6 => string '07 2015-09-03 17:06' (length=19)
  7 => string '01 2015-09-04 08:05' (length=19)
  8 => string '01 2015-09-04 11:03' (length=19)
  9 => string '' (length=0)
array (size=4)
  2 => string '01 2015-09-03 13:15 | 08:01 | 11:03 | 13:15 | 17:12' (length=51)
  3 => string '07 2015-09-03 08:15 | 08:15 | 17:06' (length=35)
  4 => string '01 2015-09-04 08:05 | 08:05 | 11:03' (length=35)
  5 => string '01 2015-09-04 11:03' (length=19)
```

Comment: I will save it to a csv file can I save it like the second array?